# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DOB') in for loop

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript

applicantToCreate is array having properties DOB.

```js
@track applicantToCreate = [];
isValidApp;
validateApplicantsfields() {    
    try{
        this.isValidApp = true;                 
        for(let i=0 ; i <= this.applicantToCreate.length ; i++){
            if(this.applicantToCreate[i].DOB == null){
                this.isValidApp = false;
                console.log(this.applicantToCreate[i].DOB); // showing null value
            }
        }
        console.log('Test'); //not getting printed
        console.log('Validation flag' + this.isValidApp); //not getting printed
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log('error 123' + error);
    }
}
```

Getting below error in console

> error 123TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DOB')

Comment: Usually this sort of error is due to lifecycle race conditions, but you have not shown us that aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initializing your `for` loop to iterate through an array using its `length` and starting at `0` you need to use `<` rather than `<=`.

In your code you have:

```
for(let i=0 ; i <= this.applicantToCreate.length ; i++){
```

That should be changed to:

```
for(let i=0 ; i < this.applicantToCreate.length ; i++){
```

---

Since arrays are indexed starting at `0`, an array's indexes will be one number lower than the length of the array.  For example, an array containing two elements and thus a `length` of `2` will have values at the indexes of `0` and `1`.

Example:

```
array = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'];
console.log(array[0]); // Prints "Item 1"
console.log(array[1]); // Prints "Item 2"
```

If you try to explicitly reference an index location that is not in the array, you get an error.

Example (using above array):

```
console.log(array[2]); // Causes an error
```

---

So in your code, if, for example, `applicantToCreate` has 5 elements, it can be indexed from `0` to `4`. But the values for `i` in your `for` loop will go from `0` to `5`, so this will error:

```
this.applicantToCreate[5].DOB
```